# This item will be deleted immediately. You can’t undo this action

Tags: permission, macos

I have a MacBook Pro which has a SSD and a hard drive. Here SSD hosts the operating system and HDD stores some files (pic., doc., etc). 1 week ago I reset my system and installed OS X El Capitan. After this whenever I try to delete a file from my storage drive I have this warning "This item will be deleted immediately. You can’t undo this action.".

Is there anyway any files from storage to go to trash instead of permanently delete?

Comment: Which "storage drive" is having issues with it's trash can? Does Disk Utility report any unfixable errors on either the HDD or SSD?

Answer (score -1):

I used Onyx to secure delete the trash and it went back to normal.